# Creating a Debug Visualizer for VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm looking to create a visualizer that is closer in the lines with Visual Studio 2022 for `System.Linq.Xml.XElement`, i.e. simplying viewing the `.ToString()` formatted representation of it.  In VS Code, I'd like to do the same for `System.Linq.Xml.XElement` and `System.Text.Json.JsonNode` variables while debugging.  The closest example I could find that might have relevant guidance is the `mock-debugger` but from skimming the code and my limited understanding of VS Code extensions, that is a little heavy handed for what I want to do.

1. Initial desire - just do a .ToString() or .ToJsonString() on the variable to get a pretty print displayed that makes it easier to view.
2. Later desire - Collapsable tree type functionality for either

Currently during debug when I have a variable with decent amount of information, I...

1. Go to the watch window
2. Type `var.ToString()`
3. Right click "Copy Value"
4. Open a new text file, paste
5. Remove leading and trailing `"`
6. Replace `\"` with `"`
7. Format the document

It's a bit tedious and I was hoping to improve that.  Is `mock-debugger` my best option at understanding how to do this or are there capabilities similar to Visual Studio's Debugger Visualizers that I could tap into?

Comment: Possibly related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-managed-objects Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Terry This seems like it isn't possible right now if you read https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5023. `mock-debugger` is a sample for implementing a new debugger adapter (which is what omnisharp provides already) and implementing a new C# debugger would be a ton of work as you probably can imagine.

Comment: a VSC debugger adapter is language agnostic, are you only supporting C#

Comment: @user - That is Visual Studio 2022 (not VSC).

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, I only want it for C#.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Yep, exactly what I want :(  I commented on feature request.